# how to sum of columns based on another column value of excel

Tags: python, excel

I would like to ask how to sum using python or excel.
Like to do summation of "number" columns based on "time" column.
Sum of the Duration for (00:00 am - 00:59 am) is (2+4) 6.
Sum of the Duration for (02:00 am - 02:59 am) is (3+1) 4.
Could you please advise how to ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a dataframe you can use groupby to accomplish this:

```
# import pandas module
import pandas as pd
# Create a dictionary with the values
data = {
    'time' : ["12:20:51", "12:40:51", "2:26:35", "2:37:35"],
    'number' : [2, 4, 3, 1]}

# create a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# or load the CSV
df = pd.read_csv('path/dir/filename.csv')
# Convert time column to datetime data type
df['time'] =  df['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S')
# add values by hour
dff = df.groupby(df['time'].dt.hour)['number'].sum()
print(dff.head(50))
```

output:

```
time
12    6
2     4
```

When you need more than one column. You can pass the columns as a list inside .groupby(). The code will look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
# Convert time column to datetime data type
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S')
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%Y')
# add values by hour
dff = df.groupby([df['date'], df['time'].dt.hour])['number'].sum()
print(dff.head(50))
# save the file
dff.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: Hi Geom, thanks for advise. may I know how to read csv instead of dictionary and how to implement using your provided code

Comment: Hey! I updated the answer. You can use pd.read_csv('filepath'). if the python file is in the same directory as the csv file you can just write the filename.csv instead of the path.

Comment: Hi Geom, only get the summation of time 2, 3, 4, 5, 11.  Didn't get the sum of time 12

Comment: Pls advise how can share the file ?

Comment: Hi Geom, I come to chat and msg. look like you are away

Comment: Hey this is incredibly silly and I spend way too much time thinking about whats causing this. But its really simple :) print(dff.head()) by default shows only 5 values. if you want to display more you need to write print(dff.head(10)). In other words it calculated all the values but did not display them. The code in the answer works perfectly.

Comment: amazing, it works. If I want to include one more column "date", may I know how to amend ? Eg- On date "01/06/2021", there will be  time "12:20:51"    number "2" and time "12:40:51" number "4". By the way how can share/upload screenshot in "Add comment" ?

Comment: I type file format in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235294/discussion-between-geom-and-field